# Win7 restore from very old file backup

Tags: backup, restore, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

I've got a Win7 computer with gigabytes of file backups over 6 years on a file server. But when I start "Backup and Restore", "Select another date" "Show All", it only lists the 20 weeks or so.

Is this a known problem? Am I doing something wrong? How do I select a backup set from 2013?

Or, is there another way to read the catalogs?

Comment: What software made the backup? What were the settings for the backups? We need much more information.

Comment: I'd agree more detail is needed for sure to give you an accurate answer. As a quick thought type workaround, change the date on the Windows OS to be a day or two above the 2013 backup date stamp and then try to restore afterwards. I've seen funny things like that before but don't remember all the specific details but if the backup is 2013-08-08 change the OS system date to 2013-08-10 and then try to restore tricking the system into thinking the date is just a few days after the backup creation time. Simple enough to try and/or rule out at least with Windows Backup files if that's what you have

Comment: The software used is "Windows 7".  But if you don't know how to set up "Backup and Restore" to do file backups on Win7, or even that "Backup and Restore" is part of Win7, then you aren't really going to be able to answer the question anyway.